# Database Tables For Multiple Roles

Tags: database-design, relational-database, database-schema, database-table

I have an architecture problem about how to store data related to a specific role in a relational database.

I have three roles, a `Subscriber Contact`, `Teacher`, and `Student`.  They are all stored in the `Users` table, but have specific properties related to each.  A student has a `SchoolId`, `Grade`, a subscriber contact has a `DistrictId`, a teacher has `ProgramId`, `SchoolId`, `Grade`.

Should I have three separate tables for subscriber contact, teacher, and student, or should I do some kind of key/value lookup?  If key/value lookup how can I do this and how can I do it for a foreign key, like `DistrictId` and `SchoolId`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate something like an inheritance. A superclass table consisting of all common attributes for roles `subscriber`, `teacher` and `student`. Then three subclass tables for each of the roles consisting of the arrtibutes unique to each. There will be a one-to-one relationship between the superclass entity and each of the subclass entities.